# Get ZXing to work

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I followed every instructions, wiki, getting started, guides, help,
etc. I could find about ZXing project.
After many many debugging, I finally manged to compile using ant
core.jar, javame.jar, and javese.jar.
I would like to integrate ZXing into my code, i.e., I wish to scan
\read a barcode and handle its data.

I've imported as external jar each of the files mentioned above. Then
I turned to https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes to use
the MultiFormatReader().
The BufferedImage class cannot be resolved. I tried whatever I know
and I even tried android's Bitmap for a workaround, but it didn't help
me either.

I know I can use an intent to read\scan the barcode, but I wish to
handle it myself and not to install a "3rd party" application.

Can anyone please help me understand how can I do so?
Few lines of code will be appreciated.

And again, I only want to scan\read a barcode and analyze its data.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest answer is that you should not use `javase.jar` in an Android app. It is code intended for JavaSE. Not all JavaSE classes are in Android. In particular Android does not have AWT classes like `BufferedImage`.

You only want to include `core.jar` in your project. Then write your Android app using it.

Comment: Sean thank you for your response, and for sharing your implementation. But it doesn't seem to work, and you have not told me something new. I am familiar with the fact the BufferedImage is not a part of JavaSE, I thought you are going to help me resolve the issue. If you wish to share your implementation, how come you didn't provide a proper documentation for it? anyway, any help will be deeply appreciated. (I never tried so much guessing)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. BufferedImage *is* part of JavaSE. It *is not* part of Android. So, it is not surprising you cannot include code like `javase.jar`, which uses BufferedImage, in an Android project. That is the error you report, and I provided the solution: don't include anything but `core.jar`. (`javame.jar` is JavaME code, and won't work or be useful in Android.) I am an author of ZXing, so I have shared my entire implementation of everything with you in the project, so I further don't understand.

Comment: I had no intention to be mean, please accept my apology for that. Anyway, what shall I do in order to use BufferedImage? can you please put your sharp knowledge into a few lines of code? thanks.

Comment: You *can't use BufferedImage in Android*. It does not exist. There is no code that will make it exist. Again, here is the answer: *do not import `javase.jar` or `javame.jar` and it will not produce this error*!

Comment: so the only option is have is to use an intent? there is no way for me to truly reuse your implementation and integrate it into my application?

Comment: I am really lost here. No. You see `android/`? This is complete source code to a working Android project. It is Apache Licensed for you to reuse however you want. I don't know what more you could want.

Comment: @SeanOwen I sow some internet tutorials that add core.jar and javese.jar to the project libraries... why we should avoid avoid importing javase.jar and javame.jar to our android projet...? iluminate us please!!

Comment: You never want to include `javase.jar`. It's not for Android at all. You don't need `core.jar` either if you're integrating by Intent. Anything that says otherwise is wrong; trust me, i'm the author!

Answer (score 4):

Jackson I too suggest you the way suggested by inazaruk.But if you are still having issues integrating that part of code ([zxing-android](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android)).

- Just download [zxing-core](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core)
- Import this core project to your eclipse
- In your app's Eclipse build path add reference of zxing-core project so that it is not **compiled by JVM but by Dalvik** (just avoid using jar file because it is compiled with JVM) and simply use all the classes as suggested at https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes

**EDIT:**
As stated by Sean Owen android doesn't posses BufferedImage class.You need to import these classes & satisfy their dependency.

- com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap,
- com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource,
- com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader,
- com.google.zxing.Reader
- com.google.zxing.Result
- com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer

Then you may use it like this

```
 Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
 LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap);
 BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                              source));
 Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

 Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
```

Comment: i was able to import the zxing-core. didn't know how to do the third step though. and anyway, i followed the DeveloperNotes but the BufferedImage cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Mr Jackson if you have no issues now with the jar then you need not add the project to your build path.See **edited** section above

Comment: Thanks! now all I need is to capture an image, and open it using the FileInputStream. right?

Comment: @Mr Jackson Yea .Though there are other ways too like directly decoding InputStream to read barcode ,etc ,etc.Just choose whatever is efficient for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for my experimental app:

- Downloaded Android version of ZXing Barcode Scanner ([here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android))
- Converted this project into [Android Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)
- Removed all the functionality I didn't need
- Modified `CaptureActivity` the way I wanted, so its better integrated with my app.

I found this way was easier, because Android has some problems with uniform Camera support across different devices, and guys from ZXing already took care of it.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i've download the whole project. i can extract the library from it (/android/), but what should i do with the files? copy them to my project?

Comment: just now i understood you. i've created a new android project from a source and redirected it to /andoroid/ directory from zxing. but i get too many errors. here is a screenshot http://i52.tinypic.com/16gcwav.png

Comment: There is no way I can guess what your problems are by that screenshot :) Please post compilation error logs.

Comment: I think that those errors are due to an unacceptable char in the XML file. Once you clean up the XML the R file will be generated and all the errors in the packages will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys Actually I also stuck in this problem. But finally I run this project successfully. When we download zxing project and simply we import it but there are number for error comes because many file are missing.

Actually these files are distributed in whole projects. So if you search these files in Zxing-master you can find easily. Copy these files and simply copy in your projects as in my workspace it is "CaptureActivity". May be one problem is also come due to compilation error which due to Java Compiler (This project requires atleast Java 1.7 and Android OS 4.4).

Whatever i know when running this project I explained. Any query leave a comment.